# How can objects with immediate value be receivers?

Tags: ruby, object, messaging

In Ruby, even though certain objects have immediate value, (e.g. `Fixnum` and `symbol` objects), you can still treat them like any other object.

Intuitively, I am having trouble understanding how this is done. However, I do have a hunch.

---

Objects that have immediate value are bound to variable names directly, where as for other 'normal' objects, a reference to said object is bound to the variable names instead.

Because variables bound to objects with immediate value are bound to a direct encoding of the object itself and this encoding has to fit into an `unsigned long`, how does Ruby know where to go when I say `8.to_s` to handle the message (to look for the method)?

Normally, a reference to the class that the object is an instance of (or a reference to a singleton class) is contained as part of the state of the object. In other words, the object has directions for where to go next.

How does Ruby do this when all it has is an `unsigned long` at its disposal to encapsulate the object?

**I presume it sets up a global constant that references the appropriate class when it is initially building the environment.** Am I correct in this assumption?

If this is the case, how does Ruby determine that the thing it is looking at is a `Fixnum` object, or a `symbol` object or what have you? (Normally it doesn't care, it just follows links in search of a method name, but in this case, it would need to know what the type of object it is dealing with is, so it knows which reference to follow.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immediate values in Ruby are still Ruby VALUEs, but they're masked with a special flag that tells Ruby what kind of immediate a given VALUE contains. Fixnums, for example, are just the [unsigned long value left-shifted and tagged with the 0x01 bit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0db407836bf7871fdee9e32357bd90c3ddaa1e11/include/ruby/ruby.h#L234-L236).

Given a VALUE, Ruby can then check if it is an immediate value by masking it against [RUBY_IMMEDIATE_MASK (0x07)](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0db407836bf7871fdee9e32357bd90c3ddaa1e11/include/ruby/ruby.h#L390-L394). If it is an immediate, then it then [treats it as an instance of that immediate type](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/0db407836bf7871fdee9e32357bd90c3ddaa1e11/include/ruby/ruby.h#L1652-L1683).

Comment: Can you elaborate on the nature of the masking operation? It is an AND mask? so its looking for a result of `0...0111`? If it gets this result then it looks to the least significant bit as a flag for which class to go to?

Comment: If you look at the bits I linked, the code and masks are there - the mask is OR'd with the shifted long to produce a new long which encodes the long's value and its status as a Fixnum immediate. The 4 least significant bits appear to be used to encode immediate types, though Fixnums only need 1 additional bit.